# wget doesn't support https

Tags: wget, https

I want to download `https://example.com` using the `wget` command, but it says “unsupported/unrecognized protocol”. I tried using the `--secure protocol=''` but that does not work.
I downloaded the tar file from GNU wget and tried configuring that but I failed.

Here is an example of what I see:

```
bash-2.05$ wget https://www.facebook.com/
https://www.facebook.com/: Unknown/unsupported protocol.
bash-2.05$
```

Hi folks  thanks for the answers, the verified the version of my wget it says as below

```
bash-2.05$ wget -V
GNU Wget 1.6

Copyright (C) 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic <hniksic@arsdigita.com>.
```

and I have no idea if my wget is compiled by SSL and the SSL is enabled or not.
Could you please let me know how to compile the `wget` command.  I tried running the `configure` file and then typed `make` command, that gives me command not found error.  Even after running the configuration file it does not give me any `wget` file created in `/usr/local/`.

```
bash-2.05$ cd wget-1.10.1
bash-2.05$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-ssl
bash-2.05$ make
bash: make: command not found
```

the version I downloaded is
`wget-1.10.1.tar`

[image: wget command version]
[image: configure command generated log]

Comment: Please update your question to include the exact comment being run and the exact error being displayed.

Comment: Also, what operating system and version are you using?

Comment: 1. What are you trying to get with wget, as wget normally requires a URL containing a file? 2. Is your wget compiled with SSL support? 3. Is `bash-2.05` really your bash version?  Mine is 4.3.33.

Comment: Is this an embedded system? It feels like this is actually something like a `busybox` version of `wget`.

Comment: @roaima The message I get from Busybox is `wget: not an http or ftp url: …` This seems to be neither GNU wget nor Busybox. Either way, it obviously doesn't support HTTPS and the solution is to install a different version or a different tool that supports HTTPS.

Comment: [The post revisions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/217028/revisions) says that the screenshot is not provided by OP.  We'd better not try to infer any info from it.

Comment: @AravindaGaddam Are you the same person as OP (@user124096)?  Besides that, you might need to run make as `/usr/ccs/bin/make` on Solaris 9.  I recommend you to add `/usr/ccs/bin` in `PATH`.

Comment: From your version output, it looks as if we are now on the right path, i.e. that version has no SSL Support, but is too old to tell us which flags are set.  As soon as we find your `make` command, you should be in business.  I learned something new today.  I had no idea, that you could `make` newer versions of installed tools on a per user basis on a hosted system.  Thanks for the requested info... +1

Answer (score 8):

### Solution

Verify your `wget` binary is compiled with SSL support enabled.  My output when I try the command you gave:

```
$ wget https://www.facebook.com
--2015-07-19 15:27:17--  https://www.facebook.com/
Resolving www.facebook.com (www.facebook.com)... 31.13.66.1, 2a03:2880:f013:1:face:b00c:0:1
Connecting to www.facebook.com (www.facebook.com)|31.13.66.1|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser [following]
--2015-07-19 15:27:18--  https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser
Reusing existing connection to www.facebook.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                                                              [ <=>                                                                                                                                                                 ]  29.21K  --.-KB/s   in 0.04s  

2015-07-19 15:27:18 (775 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [29916]

$
```

Given no fully Qualified URL downloads the default page `index.html` which contains tags etc.  All this page will tell me when viewed via a browser is that my browser is not supported, in other words: We don't support fetching of pages via `wget`.

```
$ eix wget

[I] net-misc/wget
     Available versions:  1.16 ~1.16.1 ~1.16.2 ~1.16.3 {debug gnutls idn ipv6 nls ntlm pcre +ssl static test uuid zlib}
     Installed versions:  1.16(11:25:57 AM 07/19/2015)(idn ipv6 nls pcre ssl zlib -debug -gnutls -ntlm -static -test -uuid)
     Homepage:            http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/
     Description:         Network utility to retrieve files from the WWW
```

### Per Comment

Here's what a version output looks like,  in case you've never seen Gentoo based output (Notice `-DHAVE_LIBSSL`):

```
$ wget -V
wget -V
GNU Wget 1.16 built on linux-gnu.

+digest +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file +nls -ntlm +opie -psl +ssl/openssl 

Wgetrc: 
    /etc/wgetrc (system)
Locale: 
    /usr/share/locale 
Compile: 
    x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H 
    -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/etc/wgetrc" -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/share/locale" -I. 
    -I../lib -I../lib -DHAVE_LIBSSL -march=amdfam10 -O2 -pipe 
Link: 
    x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -DHAVE_LIBSSL -march=amdfam10 -O2 -pipe 
    -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed -lpcre -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lidn ftp-opie.o 
    openssl.o ../lib/libgnu.a 

Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic <hniksic@xemacs.org>.
Please send bug reports and questions to <bug-wget@gnu.org>.
```

---

Notice that ssl does not contain a minus in the Installed Versions line from the Gentoo based output, meaning I have compiled SSL support on my Gentoo box.  In order to go further, would you please update your question with your distribution.

Comment: `wget -V` should include a line showing https support.  On my Mint 17 default install is returns `+digest +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file +nls +ntlm +opie +ssl/openssl`

Comment: @steve I'll add a `wget -V`  Something tells me there is more going on here as his bash version is 2.05...

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone else is coming across this error from within vmWare ESXi or another BusyBox environment, you aren't actually using `wget`:

Output from `wget -V` for me:

```
wget: invalid option -- 'V'
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2018-07-23 19:34:44 PDT) multi-call binary.

Usage: wget [-csq] [-O FILE] [-Y on/off] [-P DIR] [-U AGENT] URL...

Retrieve files via HTTP or FTP

    -s  Spider mode - only check file existence
    -c  Continue retrieval of aborted transfer
    -q  Quiet
    -P DIR  Save to DIR (default .)
    -O FILE Save to FILE ('-' for stdout)
    -U STR  Use STR for User-Agent header
    -Y  Use proxy ('on' or 'off')
```

So you're out of luck. Transfer the file using a different method such as SCP from your workstation.

Comment: https over `wget` is supporting after ESXi 6.7 Update 2

Comment: Maybe a solution for this is just to create a new VM and boot it with a Linux LiveCD. Once it boots, login to the VM, download whatever you need with cURL or wget. On ESXi, enable ssh, and then scp the file from the VM to ESXi. I just did it and works OK. It's a two-step process, but it's very helpful if you're not physically on the same network and the file is big

Comment: crazy that this is a thing.

Answer (score 5):

Try removing the "s"... I mean just use http.

Most of the times there is a redirection from http to https active and wget seems to work with it.

Hit the address in your browser with plain http and if you get redirected to https your wget will probably work.

So.. `wget http://example.com/file`